# How to copy files with grub console?

Tags: grub2, grub, file-copy, initramfs

I have a notebook which can't boot up Ubuntu and I want to copy all of the files to an external hard drive with USB connection to save them. After I want to install a new Ubuntu to the notebook, how can I copy all of the files to an external hard drive using just the `grub` console, or `(initramfs)` console?

**Update:**

```
sudo lsblk
sudo: lsblk: command not foud
sudo vgscan
No volume groups found
sudo lvs
No volume groups found
```

Is this possible?

Comment: even the live usb, live cd doesn't see my files, that's why I need to use grub or initramfs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> After I want to install a new Ubuntu to the notebook, how can I copy...

I think you mean *first* copy the files to an external drive, *then* reinstall Ubuntu.

You can't copy files with the GRUB console: the filesystem drivers of GRUB are basically read-only. (You can write into e.g. the `/boot/grub/grubenv` file, but only by overwriting its existing contents - you cannot increase the size of the file.)

With the `initramfs` console, you would first mount the necessary filesystems (= at least the filesystem you want to copy *from* and the filesystem of the external hard drive you want to copy *to*.), and then use the regular `cp` command to copy the files.

But there is probably a better option: prepare an Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, boot from it, and then you have all the basic filesystem manipulation tools (even GUI!) available to you.

Comment: I tried with a live cd, but it does not see the filesystem... I tried also with USB live, also the same problem...

Comment: Is the source filesystem encrypted, or configured with LVM, or some other complication? There may be some steps you need to take first. Please boot with a Live USB, run `sudo lsblk` and `sudo vgscan; sudo pvs; sudo lvs` and edit the outputs into your original question.

Comment: no, it isn't, but seems to be something wrong with `(initramfs)` because I can't `cd` to ` home` folder for example. and it says `/bin/sh: fsck: not found` if I try to run fsck.

Comment: I updated my question but I don't know if this is a possible result, because I see the system files from grub

Comment: In `(initramfs)`, the real root filesystem may not be mounted yet: you have a very basic environment which does not include `/home`, for example.  If you see system files from GRUB, you are most likely seeing the contents of `/boot`, which is often a separate filesystem when disk encryption and/or LVM is used. And the first command I asked for was `sudo lsblk`, as in "LiSt BLocK devices", not "lbsk".

Comment: how can I see all of my files from `(initramfs)`?

Comment: You need to mount your root filesystem, switch to it, then mount all the other filesystems (if you have any). And as `initramfs` has just a bare minimum of tools available, it will be really difficult to determine the right commands to do so (because I don't know enough about *your* disk layout yet). That's why using the Live USB would be a better choice: there would be a lot more tools available.

Comment: but how can I use live USB or CD if IT doesn't see the files on hard disk?